# Definite article use. Baseline characteristics of (the) included patients

Tags: british-english, definite-articles

Could you help me with definite article use in a table caption. Should I use or not "the" there?

> Table 1. Baseline characteristics of included patients.

> Table 1. Baseline characteristics of the included patients.

Comment: Why not "The baseline..."? Titles and captions are often not complete sentences and might not comply with English grammar 'rules'.

Comment: Articles are always a struggle for me. But writing "the baseline..." indicates specific measured characteristics. As a reader, I do not know these characteristics until I haven't read the table? Or the definite article is still appropriate, as "baseline characteristics" are first mentioned in the text of this sentence will work and without any article?